# Can you use Lightcouch to query documents by filter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchdb

I am using lightcouch for my spring boot application and I need to be able to query my CouchDb database for documents based on a provided filter. Since these filters can always be different, I can't make use of a preset view. I am looking for something that would work in a similar way of the normal find like below:

```
public List<MyEntity> getEntities(MyFilter myFilter)
{
   return dbClient.find(resourceFilter, MyEntity.class);
}
```

myFilter would be a Map object which I would use to query documents based on certain values provided in this map. Is it possible? Is there an approach to achieve what I want?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightCouch provides a method for querying CouchDB using mango selectors.

See [CouchDbClientBase.java](https://github.com/lightcouch/LightCouch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lightcouch/CouchDbClientBase.java#L272)

```
 /**
 * Find documents using a declarative JSON querying syntax.
 * @param <T> The class type.
 * @param jsonQuery The JSON query string.
 * @param classOfT The class of type T.
 * @return The result of the query as a {@code List<T> }
 * @throws CouchDbException If the query failed to execute or the request is invalid.
 */
public <T> List<T> findDocs(String jsonQuery, Class<T> classOfT) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`LightCouch` internal API allows for a user-defined raw HTTP request to execute against a database. This can be done through the  [CouchDbClient#executeRequest](http://www.lightcouch.org/javadocs/org/lightcouch/CouchDbClientBase.html#executeRequest-org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase-) method.

I'm not using `LightCouch` in my Java project but [Apache HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/project-reports.html) together with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Below example assumes `CouchDB` being installed on your local computer and both, user and password to be "admin". It could be easily adapted to use `CouchDbClient#executeRequest`.

The `mangoSelector` parameter in the `find` method must comply with the [CouchDB selector syntax](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/find.html#selector-syntax).

```
public class CouchDBAccess {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5984/";
    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private final Header[] httpHeaders;

    public CouchDBAccess() {
        this.httpHeaders = new Header[] { //
                new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"), //
                new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), //
                new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("admin:admin".getBytes())) //
        };
    }

    FindResult find(String dbName, String mangoSelector) throws IOException {
        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL + dbName + "/_find");
            httpPost.setHeaders(httpHeaders);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(mangoSelector, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                return GSON.fromJson(extractContent(response), FindResult.class);
            } else {
                // handle invalid response
            }
        }
    }

    private String extractContent(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer, defaultCharset());
        return writer.toString();
    }
}

class FindResult {
    MyEntity[] docs;
}
```

A corresponding jUnit test method could look as follows:

```
@Test
public void testFind() throws IOException {
    String mangoSelector = "{\"selector\": {\"Host\": \"local drive\"}}";
    FindResult findResult = couchDBAccess.find("data_1", mangoSelector);

    assertEquals(100, findResult.docs.length); // or whatever you expect
}
```